# firebase observeSingleEvent deprecated in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

What do I use to make a single event observe? I've tried searching the internet and can't find anything that talks about it being deprecated. And I say it's deprecated because the method is crossed out when I type it in xcode.

Should I just do regular observe, then remove it right after?

Comment: Could you please show the cross you're getting? I'm not getting anything like that.

Comment: Please share the code that causes the problem that you mention. Without such an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to say more than what iOS Geek does: "it still works for me".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it I am still using it . try using Following code . which pod version of firebase Are you using and Xcode version ?

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
      databaseRef.child("Users").observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                if snapshot.hasChild(strrr){

                    print("true rooms exist")
                    databaseRef.child("Users").child(strrr).child("Requests").child(emailIdCurrent).setValue("False")


                }else{

                    print("false room doesn't exist")
                }


            })
```

Comment: I'm using xcode 8.33.

Not sure how to get pod version of firebase. I just downloaded it yesterday though so it should be the latest version.

Comment: @DewTime It doesn't mean that it is final, you could insert wrong version number and install older one. `pod spec cat Firebase` to get version of Firebase. Also, iOS Geek is right, function still works - there must be a problem with your pods.

Comment: Sorry guys to be honest I didn't actually check the function when I made this post. Turns out it does work. But the question now is, why does xcode cross out the function?